# Join records between two tables with Django ORM

Tags: django, python-2.7, join, record

I'm slightly unfamiliar with django's ability to join record(s) between (2) tables or more.

**For example, I have two tables:**
[image: img]

In plain old SQL, I would do a inner-join on the `id` field

I have this relationship setup in django's **model.py**:

```
class Tld(models.Model):
    domainNm = models.CharField(verbose_name="",max_length=40,unique=True,validators=[RegexValidator('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$','format: domain.com only','Invalid Entry')])
    FKtoClient = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

the `User` table is the default django table (created upon initially running `python manage.py syncdb`)

How do I join these two tables on field `DomainNm` in django 1.5 ?

Sorry for the newbieness here.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give some more details on what exactly you're trying to do? For instance: Reducing the number of queries necessary to display tld_object.FKtoClient. Django's magic changes depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to join the two tables on the common field 'id' and return the DomainNm

Comment: I think `Tld.objects.all().select_related('FKtoClient')` though I'm not sure the SQL will match the exact JOIN you're imagining. Can you expand a little what is it for? Maybe there's a more django-ic solution for your problem (there usually is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, what you're really wanting is a QuerySet of all Tld objects associated with the currently logged-in User. Luckily, Django makes this fairly trivial since it populates the [`request.user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) object with the current User object for you and creates a [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/relations/) between the Tld and User models (as shown here by `user.tld_set.all()`).

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        tld_set = []
    else:
        tld_set = request.user.tld_set.all()
    context = {'tld_set': tld_set}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**index.html**:

```
<ul>
  {% for tld in tld_set %}
    <li>{{ tld }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The SQL generated from this doesn't contain any JOINs at all since Django already grabbed the User object (and it's associated id) for populating [`request.user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) before your view is ever called:

```
SELECT "rcr_tld"."id", "rcr_tld"."FktoClient_id", "rcr_tld"."domainNm"
FROM "rcr_tld"
WHERE "rcr_tld"."FktoClient_id" = 1  --Django already knows the User's id from request.user.id
```

Comment: So maybe I should have clarified. The 'User' table stores if a user is logged in or not, I'm trying to do a join on the current user logged in (based on sessionid) and joining the User table to Tld based on this user.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Ahh, I see. If you're doing this in a view, you will have access to the request.user object which Django populates for you. In which case you can do: `request.user.tld_set.all()`. That will give you a QuerySet containing every Tld object associated with the current User.

Comment: Is my syntax wrong here for doing this in a **template** ? {% request.user.tld_set.all() %}     ?

Comment: Templates don't requires parenthesis for function calls and use double braces for variables: `{{ request.user.tld_set.all }}`. Of course, this assumes that you're passing the request object into the template from the view.

Comment: Is it better practice to pass from view->template and then output on template like {{ myvardefinedinview }}? Instead of doing {{ request.user.tld_set.all }} without passing?

Comment: Can you please explain request.user.tld_set.all in your answer? Then i'll mark as good to go. It may help others on here

Comment: It's mostly just personal preference. Most people would prefer to keep the logic in the view and set a specific context variable for the User's tld set which will later be iterated over in the template.

Comment: Is it generating some sort of error? I can't find any glaring issues with my code.

Comment: (1054, "Unknown column 'Site_tld.FKtoClient_id' in 'field list'")

Comment: I think its complaining: tld_set is not a column in User  table

Comment: Try my updated views.py code in the answer above. I added a check for AnonymousUser which makes sure that the User is successfully logged in. I'm hoping that's your issue.

Comment: If I run User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id) it outputs all of the current users in the db

Comment: Want to talk on chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39948/discussion-between-codetalk-and-shane)